# StoryBook Angular - ERR! => Could not get angular cli webpack config

Tags: angular, storybook, angular-storybook

Upon executing npm run storybook, the process fails with the following error:

```
ERR! => Could not get angular cli webpack config
```

Comment: Same thing here... could not figure it out yet. I've been getting extra frustrated with Storybook lately. Love the tool, but installing it on Angular projects... GOOD LUCK!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same isssue. The fix for me was to specifically name the paths of 'root' and 'sourceRoot' in the angular.json file.

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "storybook": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/my-lib/src/lib",
      "root": "projects/my-lib",
      "architect": {
         ...
      },
    ...
    },
  ...
  },
}
```

Comment: I didn't have a storybook project in my angular.json file, but I added what you suggested, minus the "architect" property, and after resolving an additional issue, I was able to get storybook building and running. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

This error usually happens upon additional source being added for assets in the angular.json file.

Fix:

1. Remove additional sources from assets under angular.json
2. Open package.json and edit the storybook script as follows:

   "storybook": "npm run docs:json && start-storybook -p 6006 -s projects/"

Comment: Sources? What sources are you referring to? Do you mean files like CSS etc? Example please? Thank you. And if so, why would I remove files I need just to run Storybook?

Comment: I had my component library under the projects/ directory.
To use the assets of the component library in the storybook, I tried to add the paths of those assets in angular.json file of storybook (assuming storybook works similar to a normal angular project).
But I was wrong!
Storybook requires you to pass the paths of the static directories in the CLI when you are starting the storybook. This can be seen from the syntax I have share above (all you have to see is the -s flag, and the path that comes after that).